# React-Redux is saved at C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TypeScript

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I downloaded the redux library by running npm install redux on my project folder. The strange thing is that redux was saved in C:\Users\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TypeScript which is a different directory than my project's.

Why is this happening and how does webpack knows this location when i import redux it in my app?

Thank you

Comment: `npm redux` should not be a valid command; to install redux it should be `npm install redux`. OP is this a typo here?

Comment: @blaz Yes. Sorry. Fixed it.

Comment: This might be only types for the redux library. Are you sure there is no <your project>/node_modules/redux directory? BTW if you are using VSCode please check [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/16318)

Comment: Ye s im using  VSCode .Thanks